# add to passbook option not shown for a pass file

Tags: passbook

I am working on pass file creation app. Created a pass file, attached it to mail, opened it in iphone 4s with ios6 installed. Pass opened properly but add to passbook option is not being shown. Any clue on what needs to be done?

Comment: What did you set webServiceUrl to?

Comment: I did not have any callbacks for update. I am not having any weservice url. Is it mandatory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am successfully able to add the attached pass to pass book app. Something wrong with signing command. Used following one and it just worked fine.( was missing WWDR.pem previously).

`openssl smime -binary -sign -certfile WWDR.pem -signer passcertificate.pem -inkey passkey.pem -in manifest.json -out signature -outform DER -passin pass:12345`